# Monotonicity and boundness of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ x_1 = a, a\in \mathbb{R}, a > 1$$
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{5x_{n} - 4}{x_n},n \in \mathbb{N} $$

Analyse in terms of $a$, the monotonicity and boundedness of the sequence:$$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

I know that I want to be checking $a_{n+1} - a_n \le \ge 0  $ but I am not sure where to start on this and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well it's clearly bounded below by $x_{1}>1$, and it also seems to be strictly increasing if we test some values like $x_{2}=2$ and continue plugging in subsequent values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write the sequence as
$$x_{n+1}=5-\frac{4}{x_n}$$
as $x_n>0$ we have that $1<x_{n+1}<5$

therefore the sequence is bounded

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{5x_n-4}{x_n}\quad(*)$$

is also monotonically increasing if $x_1=a< 4$. Indeed for any $n$
$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=5-\frac{4}{x_{n+1}}-5+\frac{4}{x_{n}}=\frac{4}{x_{n}}-\frac{4}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{4}{x_{n}}-\frac{4x_n}{5x_n-4}=4\,\frac{5x_n-4-x_n^2}{x_n(5x_n-4)}=$$
$$=4\,\frac{(4-x_n) (x_n-1)}{x_n(5x_n-4)}>0$$
and monotonically decreasing if $x_1=a>4$

Being bounded and monotonic the sequence converge to $x$ as $n\to\infty$

Let $n\to\infty$ in $(*)$. We get

$x=\frac{5x-4}{x}\to x^2-5x+5=0\to x=4$

The solution $x=1$ is not acceptable because $x_1=a>1$

Therefore the limit is $x=4$

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that for $x_1=a=4$ the sequence is constant and is $x_n=4$ for any $n$ so obviously it converges to $4$

Hope this helps

Comment: You could say if $a \in (1, 4]$, then $x_n \in (1, 4]$ and if $a > 4$, then $x_{n>1} \in (4, 5)$  to tighten the bounds.  +1 though

Comment: Sorry to bring this so much later but if I have to analyse the boundness, $\textbf{in terms of a}$, how would I go about doing this. This part of the question awards higher marks than analysing the monotonicity.

Comment: @MathsRookie The sequence is bounded for any $a\ne 0$

Comment: The sequence is equivalent of the partial fractions $$a,5-\frac{4}{a},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}}}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}}}}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}}}}}},5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{5-\frac{4}{a}}}}}}}},\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

A graphical hint:

[image]

For any $x_1\in(1,4)$ we have $x_n\to 4$ and it remains to study what happens for $x_1\in(4,+\infty)$.
This particular map only has two fixed points, and one of them is repulsive.

Comment: for $a>4$ the sequence decreases

Comment: @Raffaele: of course, that is the non-depicted part of the iteration. Still, we have convergence towards $4$ ($4$ is an attractive fixed point).

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: for boundedness, write$$x_{n+1}=5-\frac{4}{x_n}$$and show that $x_n>1$ by induction on $n$. To get you started: $x_n>1\implies -\frac{4}{x_n}>-4$. Now show $x_n<5$ for each $n>1$. Indeed, $\frac{4}{x_n}>0$ for any $n\geq 1$.